# React-Native Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I am new to Redux in React-Native and I need help to call action. Here is my reducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
    redusername: '',
    redstatuscursa: '',
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SETUSERNAME':
            return {  ...state, redusername: action.payload }
        case 'SETSTATUSCURSA':
            return {  ...state, redstatuscursa: action.payload }    
    }
    return state
  }

export default reducer;
```

And this is in Main.js file:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
    redusername: state.redusername,
    redstatuscursa: state.redstatuscursa
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
    setusername: (user) => dispatch({ type: 'SETUSERNAME', payload: user }),
    setstatuscursa: (val) => dispatch({ type: 'SETSTATUSCURSA', payload: val })    
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

When I call this.props.setusername(this.state.username); in a function, the username is transferred to store, but when I call this.props.setstatuscursa("OK"); in componentDidMount() redstatuscursa don't change. But the last call works in onPress. What's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
   import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

   function mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=> {
    return {
    actions: {bindActionCreators({setusername,setstatuscursa,dispatch})}  
    }
}
```

Now you can dispatch your actions as :

```
this.props.actions.setusername(user)
this.props.actions.setstatuscursa(val)
```